# Export Ocean Modifier animation to game engine

Tags: ocean-simulation

I am trying to export an interactive Ocean modifier animation to be rendered in a game engine, the modifier allows the export of the displacement and foam maps, but not the animation created by intersecting objects and the foam created by such objects, Alembic exports the animated mesh very well, but does not generate any maps, and FBX does not export the animation and does not generate maps either.

Here is the test file I am using [Ocean_test.zip - 228 kb](https://www.mediafire.com/?af55t5kf2yai3tk)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Manually combine the the exported maps with the FBX generated animation in the game engine

Comment: Hola Duarte, many thanks for your reply.

The Ocean Modifier can easily export vector displacement and foam maps to use in a game engine, that's not my problem, my problem is that I cannot find a way to export the extra animation and maps of objects interacting with the ocean, like the ball in the test file I posted, I can export an Alembic file that has the ocean animation as well as the ball interaction, but it does not export the maps that goes with it.